# D5RF - Display something in HTML format before processing API requests

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Django 5 - Rest Framework**

I am building a Django REST API project. I am currently dealing with a request that takes so long to process. I want to know if I could display something like an HTML Response before the request is processed, or just like a text saying: `Loading... Please wait.`

Here is my code:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class SomeView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request):
        # I wanted to display it here.

        # -----------------
        # Some process here
        # -----------------

        # And then the actual response of the process.
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to implement a task queue system that can run long processes in the background. You can start the task from your API views and setup endpoints for checking the status of the tasks as well as the results.

Best you check out solutions such as celery "https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html" which integrates quite well with Django.